# which build tool(s) do you recommend for python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, build-automation, pyinstaller

I'm starting a small/medium-sized python project, likely in Test Driven Development. My backgrounds are more in C and java than python (I used ant and makefile)

I know that in python you might not need a build tool, but I will, because I'll use cython and PyInstaller (the thing should work on a couple of different UNIXes, without depending directly on python) and I'd like the convenience of selecting the tests form CLI, building the docs, maybe check dependencies, etc.

[Somebody](http://blog.ianbicking.org/pythons-makefile.html) is complaining that python lacks a make-like tool.
I know that few tools exist, like [scon](http://www.scons.org/) and [paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/), but I'd like to hear from real users and not just their website. Does anybody use [paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/)?

What's about the usual setup.py that comes with many packages? I looked into a few to see if there is a common usage, but I didn't find anything interesting (maybe I used the wrong examples)

Do you recommend sticking with things I already know (ant and Makefile) at least to start? If so, is there any ant extension you recommend for python (+cython+pyinstaller+pyUnit)?

---

EDIT: to avoid further answers like jwp's one, note that, for this project, I absolutely need my program being a standalone executable because it is absolutely *impossible* to have a python VM on the target platform where the executable will run. I have exactly the same hw available for compiling, so luckly I don't need to cross-compile (but I'd do the development on a more friendly Linux).

I'd also like to test if my code compile in Cython from the beginning, not to premature optimize, but just to be sure that I'm not going too far with the use of incompatible features, which would require a painful refactoring if Cython would be seriously needed.

So please focus on my actual question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your requirements suggest rather [Scons](http://www.scons.org/) which, according to their website, has more control over variety of building tasks than [Paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/). In the latter you would end up using a lot of `sh()` which runs a regular command line programs.

Recently, I started using [Paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/) which is really great to run tests, build documentations with [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), but I use only pure Python.
If you want to see what's possible with Paver I highly recommend those 2 articles:
[converting-from-make-to-paver](http://doughellmann.com/2009/01/18/converting-from-make-to-paver.html) and [writing-technical-documentation](http://doughellmann.com/2009/02/02/writing-technical-documentation-with-sphinx-paver-and-cog.html) by Doug Hellmann and you definitely want to check his pavement.py [configuration file](http://www.doughellmann.com/downloads/PyMOTW-1.89.tar.gz).

Answer (score 16):

(Edit: Avoid "premature" optimization advice. The recommendations for tooling in this answer are now outdated: [PEP-0632](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/).)

If it is at all possible, I'd suggest avoiding extension modules(C/cython) **in the beginning**. Get your all code written in Python, use a simple [`distutils`](http://www.python.org/doc/current/distutils/index.html) based configuration, run your tests using `-m` (`python -m mypkg.test.testall`, or whatever; import [`unittest`](http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/unittest.html)).

Once you get your project to a comfortable state, then start tackling some optimizations with cython and the extra project management that comes with that. distutils can build extension modules, so I'm not sure you'll need make/scons..

Comment: +1: Avoid build tools and C until you absolutely need them, and can prove that you have the right algorithm, but it's too slow.  Until you can prove that you need C, avoid it.

Comment: I understand this point, and agree in general. But in this specific case, I absolutely need C from the start. I could avoid optimization (and maybe Cython) but I need the program being a standalone executable (and hence pyInstaller) because having a python VM on the target platform is not an option. I'd also like to test if my code compile in Cython, just to be sure that I'm not going too far with the use of incompatible features, which would make it useless, when Cython would be seriously needed.

Comment: Cython is pretty good. Just avoid closures in your code and the rest would be minor refactoring(well, and I've seen talk of closures on cython-dev so that might not be a necessary practice for much longer).

AFA the absolute need for C, have you seen the ctypes module? Or do Python extension modules not suffice?

I haven't used pyInstaller, is it anything like py2exe? Could have sworn py2exe worked with setuptools/distutils.

Cython will give *straight pure-Python* a 30% speed increase. Chances are that you will want more than that if this app reqs performance. (ie, "cython lang" or C)

Comment: In short, other than pyInsaller, I don't understand why distutils doesn't suffice. When I've used Cython in the past, I manually generated the .c file, checked it into the scm, and then used distutils to build the extension module. However, I did this after I was done writing and testing the .py file.

Comment: Q: How can I do X? A: I don't understand why you'd want to do X, try Y instead... -1

Comment: Q: How can I do X? A: You should try Y first. If that doesn't work for you, then do X.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) for this, sometimes in combination with Ant for more complex stuff, or for integrating with other builds. In general it has worked well for me, but I've heard some people at #python (freenode) complain about a generally low source quality for this package, and recommending the standard [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/).

One thing to really watch out with if you are used to Java (like me), is that python does not support split packages. That is, you cannot put site.db in src/site/db, site.view in src2/site/view, put src and src2 on PYTHONPATH and the expect everything to work. This caused major headaches for me with the build tools, it worked a bit sporadically :)

Answer (score 4):

One tool I love is virtualenv: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

from the site:
*What It Does
virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.
The basic problem being addressed is one of dependencies and versions, and indirectly permissions. Imagine you have an application that needs version 1 of LibFoo, but another application requires version 2. How can you use both these applications? If you install everything into /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages (or whatever your platform's standard location is), it's easy to end up in a situation where you unintentionally upgrade an application that shouldn't be upgraded.*

You can also try: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout

from the site:
*The Buildout project provides support for creating applications, especially Python applications. It provides tools for assembling applications from multiple parts, Python or otherwise. An application may actually contain multiple programs, processes, and configuration settings.*

Tried it a couple of times, excellent for deploying development envrionments, maybe it's too much for your needs.

I've also been told and read in a couple of places that nose is a very cool testing tool
http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/, I'm looking for some free time to try it.

Hope It helps
Cheers,
Ale

Answer (score 3):

> to avoid further answers like jwp's one, note that, for this project, I absolutely need my program being a standalone executable because it is absolutely impossible to have a python VM on the target platform where the executable will run. I have exactly the same hw available for compiling, so luckly I don't need to cross-compile (but I'd do the development on a more friendly Linux).
>
> I'd also like to test if my code compile in Cython from the beginning, not to premature optimize, but just to be sure that I'm not going too far with the use of incompatible features, which would require a painful refactoring if Cython would be seriously needed.

If all you're looking for is to have a stand-alone executable, you don't need to run Cython.  There are a few good libraries for doing this:

- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
- [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)

However, to run Python code, you're simply going to *have to* install an interpreter or virtual machine on the target machine in some form or fashion.  The solutions I presented involve merely embedding the interpreter to make it easier to install.  In fact, I'm pretty sure (but could be wrong) that Cython won't allow you to build a stand-alone executables.  It's mainly meant for creating extensions to the Python interpreter.

However, there are a couple of other alternatives.  If you have a Java interpreter on the target machine, you can run [Jython](http://www.jython.org/Project/).  There's also a [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IronPython) for .net.  However, you will still have to distribute the runtimes for these languages with your project.

In short, if you want a stand-alone executable with no dependencies, your only option is pretty much to go with straight C or C++.

Comment: Thanks for the message. As I wrote in the question, this is linux/unix, thus py2exe and py2app are not the right tool. I evaluated freeze.py but finally opted for pyInstaller, as I also mentioned in the question. Finally yes, Cython (alone) does not allow to build stand-alone executable, but pyInstaller does (and it works nicely with pyInstaller)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple python based build tool. Check out [pynt](https://github.com/rags/pynt). Tasks in [pynt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynt) are just (decorated) python function. It also support Rake style parameter passing to tasks.